# error in establishing DB connection in Perl script?

Tags: perl, dbi, sqlanywhere, dbd

I am using perl 5.24. I am trying to learn Perl.

I had written a simple Perl code to connect to a DB. But gives error stating

> `DBI connect('database=vms','DBA',...) failed: (no error string) at simpleperl.pl line 13.`

The code is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use DBI;
use DBD::SQLAnywhere;

my $driver = "SQLAnywhere"; 
my $database = "vms";
my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:database=$database";
my $userid = "DBA";
my $password = "admin";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $userid, $password,{RaiseError => 1}) or die ("died connection:$DBI::errstr");

if($dbh)
{
    print "Connection Established";
}
```

Can anyone point out what might be the problem here?

Comment: First use `use strict;` and `use warnings;` as those will catch a bunch of errors. And don't `use DBD::<Driver>` directly. `DBI` will handle the driver for you.

Comment: I think `database=$database` must be `ENG=$database`. See te comment in the source code: `# If dbname starts with something that doesn't look like
 # a connect string parameter ('label=value;' format) then
 # 'ENG=' is prefixed.
`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44906829

Answer (score 2):

Note the following in [DBD::SQLAnywhere](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::SQLAnywhere) documentation:

> `$dbh = DBI->connect( 'dbi:SQLAnywhere:ENG=demo', $userid, $passwd );`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;    
use DBI;

my $driver = "SQLAnywhere"; 
my $database = "vms";
my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:ENG=$database";
my $userid = "DBA";
my $password = "admin";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $userid, $password, {RaiseError => 1});

print "Connection established\n";

$dbh->disconnect;
```

Note also the following:

- Always use `strict` and `warnings`.
- You do not need `use DBD::SQLAnywhere;`. `DBI` will pick the driver based on what you specify in the connection string.
- You specified `{RaiseError => 1}` in your connection options. That means, there is no need for the `or die`. `DBI` will croak if `connect` fails.
- You probably want `AutoCommit => 0` to go with that `RaiseError => 1`.
- There is no need for the `if ($dbh)` following the connection attempt. You won't get there unless `connect` succeeded.

Given that fixing the connection string did not solve the problem and I do not have an instance of a SQLAnywhere database to test things, I am going to recommend you add:

```
DBI->trace( 5 );
```

before the `connect` call, and update your question with the trace information. See also [TRACING](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#TRACING).

Comment: I ran the code which you suggested . It still gives the same error
**DBI connect('ENG=vms','DBA',...) failed: (no error string) at AnotherSimplePerl.pl line 12.**

Comment: I am assuming there is indeed a database called `vms` to which you can connect via other means. Is that assumption correct?

Comment: Yes there is a database called vms.